# MVC 3 details view strong type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

hi i am having trouble fetching the detail of my product, the code `Sneaker snkr=_sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.Find(id);` does not seem to work it saying that the `.Find` 'does not contain a definition for find'

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    private Forest.Models.ForestDBEntities
        _music_categoryDataModel = new Forest.Models.ForestDBEntities();
    //private Models.music_categories music_categoryToCreate;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Forest.Models.music_categories> Categories = _music_categoryDataModel.music_categories.ToList<Forest.Models.music_categories>();
        return View("Categories",Categories);
    }

    public ActionResult Details (int id)
    {
        Sneaker snkr=_sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.Find(id);

        return View(snkr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you include the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: yes `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using sneaker_info.Models;`

Comment: `Find` is not a LINQ extension.

Comment: Simply use `First()` or `Where() with First()` or even `Single()`

Answer (score 2):

`_sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers` is most likely going to be an [IQueryable<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [IEnumerable<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckzcawb8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which don't have a method called `Find`. [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a method on `List<T>`, so the only way you can use this would be to call `ToList()` before `Find` (which can lead to negative performance implications depending on the collection).

There are various LINQ extensions which make querying these types of collections trivial, [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be an adequate choice here

```
Sneaker snkr = _sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: i still have the same problem but now its `x.Id` saying  'does not contain a definition for find'

Comment: @user3274859 `x` represents a `Sneaker`, the example assumes you have an `Id` property, if you don't then you would need to use the relevant property in it's place. I doubt you will be seeing that error because there is no usage of `Find` here.